# Which Javascript Menu is Used on the Oracle Website?

Tags: javascript, menu

Does somebody know a Javascript menu (in Jquery if possible) similar to the javascript menu used in Oracle?

And it must work for ie7+ and ff2+

http://www.oracle.com/index.html

This menu does not display a list of element instead, it show an entire div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may look for something like [this menu](http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/mega-drop-downs-w-css-jquery/)

[Demo here](http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/examples/mega-dropdowns/)

Comment: Thanks you. it is exactly what i was searching fo (with some css-tweak)